UIMA RUTA Script RETAINTYPE Issues
I have used WORDTABLE for finding one to 100 number spell out.
Code:
WORDTABLE NumberSpellOutTable = 'NumberSpellOut.csv';
DECLARE MaybeNumberSpellOut_SPACE(STRING spellOut, STRING number,INT wordtoNumber); 

// SPACE => MaybeNumberSpellOut_SPACE
RETAINTYPE(SPACE); 
Document{->MARKTABLE(MaybeNumberSpellOut_SPACE, 1, NumberSpellOutTable,true,0,"",0, "spellOut" =1,"number" = 2,"wordtoNumber"=3)};  
RETAINTYPE;    
 
// BREAK => MaybeNumberSpellOut
RETAINTYPE(BREAK);               
DECLARE Annotation MaybeNumberSpellOut(STRING spellOut, STRING number,INT wordtoNumber); 
Document{->MARKTABLE(MaybeNumberSpellOut, 1, NumberSpellOutTable,true,0,"",0, "spellOut" =1,"number" = 2,"wordtoNumber"=3)}; 
RETAINTYPE; 
   
//BREAK,SPACE => MaybeNumberSpellOut_Space_Break
RETAINTYPE(BREAK,SPACE);               
DECLARE Annotation MaybeNumberSpellOut_Space_Break(STRING spellOut, STRING number,INT wordtoNumber); 
Document{->MARKTABLE(MaybeNumberSpellOut_Space_Break, 1, NumberSpellOutTable,true,0,"",0, "spellOut" =1,"number" = 2,"wordtoNumber"=3)}; 
RETAINTYPE;                  

//WS => MaybeNumberSpellOut_WS
RETAINTYPE(WS);               
DECLARE Annotation MaybeNumberSpellOut_WS(STRING spellOut, STRING number,INT wordtoNumber); 
Document{->MARKTABLE(MaybeNumberSpellOut_WS, 1, NumberSpellOutTable,true,0,"",0, "spellOut" =1,"number" = 2,"wordtoNumber"=3)}; 
RETAINTYPE;                  

// No RETAINTYPE => MaybeNumberSpellOut_No_RETAINTYPE
DECLARE Annotation MaybeNumberSpellOut_No_RETAINTYPE(STRING spellOut, STRING number,INT wordtoNumber); 
Document{->MARKTABLE(MaybeNumberSpellOut_No_RETAINTYPE, 1, NumberSpellOutTable,true,0,"",0, "spellOut" =1,"number" = 2,"wordtoNumber"=3)};

NumberSpellOut.csv:
One hundred seventeen;117;117
One hundred;100;100
zero;0;0
One;1;1
Two;2;2
Three;3;3
Four;4;4
Five;5;5
Six;6;6
Seven;7;7
Eight;8;8
Nine;9;9
Ten;10;10
Output from ruta :

Expected Output:
 One hundred seventeen
 One

